# Can't delete file on Azure with Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service, delete-file, ucanaccess

I have Spring Boot REST Application that runs on Azure on app service api-app.
I need to read access database files from this path on azure "D:\home\site\wwwroot\database>".

When I read a file from that location I need to delete them.

This is my code for read and delete file from azure, but when I go to **KUDU** Debug Console, file was not deleted.

```
public  List<AccessFeedDTO> download(Long fileId) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException, SQLException{
    if(fileId!=null){
        File file = null;
    try {

        ImportFileFeedDTO importFileFeedDTO= importFileFeedService.getFeedFile(fileId);

        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("spartanv3files");
        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFile cloudFile = rootDir.getFileReference(importFileFeedDTO.getFile_uuid());
        System.out.println(cloudFile.getName());
        System.out.println(cloudFile.downloadText());

        file = new File ("D:/home/database/"+importFileFeedDTO.getFile_uuid());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        cloudFile.download(fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        System.gc();



        List<AccessFeedDTO> accessFeedsDTOlist= accessFeedMapper.accessFeedEntitytolistofAccessFeedDTO(accessFeedRepository.getAllAccessFeeds(importFileFeedDTO.getFile_uuid()));
        file.delete();
        return accessFeedsDTOlist;
    } catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey) {
        throw new RuntimeException(invalidKey.getMessage());

    }finally{
        file.delete();
    }
    }else{
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

And this is the way how I set up a connection to that file (access database) on azure. I used UCanAccess to connect to temporary Access files for reading data.

```
public Connection getAccessFeedConnection(String fileName){

try {
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/home/database/"+fileName+";immediatelyReleaseResources=true");
    return connection;
} catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    return connection;
}   
}
```

And here is how I use  connection to pic up parameters from access database

```
public List<AccessFeedEntity> getAllAccessFeeds(String dataBaseName) throws SQLException{
    Connection connection = accessConfig.getAccessFeedConnection(dataBaseName);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TBLFEEDS");
    try {
        List<AccessFeedEntity> listofaccessFeedEntity = new ArrayList<AccessFeedEntity>();
        while(resultSet.next()){

            AccessFeedEntity accessFeedEntity = new AccessFeedEntity();
            accessFeedEntity.setFeedid(resultSet.getLong("ID"));
            accessFeedEntity.setFeedname(resultSet.getString("NAME"));
            listofaccessFeedEntity.add(accessFeedEntity);

        }
        connection.close();
        statement.close();
        resultSet.close();
           return listofaccessFeedEntity;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.close();
        statement.close();
        resultSet.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try {
            connection.close();
            statement.close();
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to delete that file on **Kudu** Debug Console I get the following message "*The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.*
"

When I try this on localhost file is deleted. But on Azure doesn't work.

Where I went wrong and where I did not close the stream?

Or can someone help me to delete this file on other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the app and deleting it from Kudu while the app is off.

Comment: In that case works. But I want to delete the file without stopping the server.